# Input loses focus on start typing in THEME

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to develop a react-native app for that I design a custom theme component and include my screen in the theme using `this.props.child`. The problem is that the input field in the screen loses focus and the keyboard gets dismissed after each character I type, as in `onChange` I am updating state variables which may re-render the whole theme.

I have tried many solutions given on Github like a passing unique key to the input field, but they don't work.

This is how my theme component looks like:

```
import Header from './header'
import footer from './footer'

export default class Theme extends Component {

    render() {
        //------this is my header component----
        <Header/>
        <View>
        //------this is my Body  in which i include my sceen content----
        {this.props.children}
        </View>

         //------this is my footer component----
        <footer/>
    }
}
```

Here is my screen with the input field:

```
import Theme from "../../components/Theme";
import { Input, Button } from "react-native-elements";

export default  class ChangePassword extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = {

        inputs:{
            old_password : {value:null, errorMesssage:""}

        }
    }
}


 setValues = async (key, value) => {

    let { inputs } = this.state;

      inputs[key]["value"] = value;
      inputs[key]["errorMessage"] = "";


      await this.setState({ inputs });


  }

    render(){

    let {inputs}=this.state;
    return(
            <Theme>

            <Input
                    key="Current_password"
                    ref="Current_password"
                    containerStyle={styles.containerStyle}
                    inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
                    label="Current password"
                    value={inputs.old_password.value}
                    errorMessage={inputs.old_password.errorMessage}
                    errorStyle={styles.inputErrorStyle}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    autoFocus={true}
                    onChangeText={(val) => {
                    this.setValues("old_password", val);
                    }}

                />


            </Theme>
    )

    }

}
```

Please help me to solve the issue, I want `onChangeText` to update my state variable without dismissing the keyboard.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil Singhal, welcome to SO! I wonder if the issue is not elsewhere. The state update doesn't seem like it should cause the input to loose focus. Could you share the full content of `setValues`, and show where `inputs.old_password.value` comes from?

Comment: @LaurentS I have updated the code with the constructor and setValues function..hope that will help you

Comment: @NikhilSinghal can you regenerate your problem on [expo](https://snack.expo.io/) and share with us?

Comment: Is there a reason you call `setState` with `await`? I don't think you need it. Is there something else in `setValues`, because I can't see why this code would cause your input to lose focus

Comment: added it in expo https://snack.expo.io/@sonnywanger/rn-test but did not reproduce this problem on iPhone

Answer (score 0):

How about lifecycle hook - shouldComponentUpdate where you can decide when the Component should rerender?

Answer (score 0):

Disable autofocus

```
 autoFocus={false}
```